# How to disable automatic Java static imports?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import

A recent version of IntelliJ (16+ EAP) started automatic Java static imports.

To be clear: I am OK with non-static imports.

Can I disable only static imports?

Comment: I don't recall these imports being automatic...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are checkboxes for controlling automatic importing at File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import. Now there's only one, but in the next EAP, there will be separate ones for class and method/field imports.

After IDEA 2016.2.1, it's controlled by `Show import suggestions for static methods and field` checkbox.

Comment: Hello Peter!  I know you well from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com.  Thanks for the update.  =)

Comment: Hi Kevin :) Apparently the correctly working setting will be delayed until next EAP (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150972)

Comment: I'm still unable to find this setting in IDEA 2016.2.1, is there an issue to track the progress ?

Comment: It's controlled by "Show import suggestions for static methods and field" checkbox. Do you need anything different?

Comment: I've searched for an option to disable automatic _static_ import only in order to prevent IDEA from breaking my code. That's obviously a bug, so I will create an issue or add a comment to IDEA-72227. Thanks Peter!

Comment: I've ended up commenting on [IDEA-24849](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-24849) which reflects exactly the original question (and unfortunately isn't resolved yet).

Answer (score 2):

In IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.5, I solved this by increasing the numbers here:

```
Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java ->
    Class count to use import with '*': 50
    Names  count to use static import with '*': 30
```